# Attempting to open excel files with win32com.client.dispatch when files handles are already taken

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I am currently trying to make some of my python scripts that regularly access excel files a bit more robust.

I have some of my code that looks like the following:

```
filename = temp.xlsm
xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Workbooks.Open(filename,ReadOnly=1)
xl.Application.Run(macro1)
xl.Application.Run(macro2)
xl.Workbooks(1).Close(SaveChanges=1)
xl.Application.Quit()
xl=0
```

Most of the time my macros and the execution of this code would run perfectly fine, however since I'm constantly modifying my embedded VBA macro code there are going to be times where my macros crash and because of this my filename handle will remain in use by an excel background task.  The only way to resolve this contention is to use the windows process Explorer to find the process that has the filename handle in use and then kill the excel.exe process.

Is there a way to modify my code above such that if the file handle is in use that this python script will automagically kill the excel background process for me and then run it again OR when the macro1,2,3,4 are being executed if they do not successful run to completion have the excel background task die at that point...

Comment: I'm thinking that if there's a way using os.system to return to me the PID of excel that currently has the file handle then I could use that PID to invoke an os.system(taskkill........)

Comment: Your macros can return a result via Application.Run. Maybe write your macros to indicate success/failure?

Comment: That's true, I've modified the code in order to do this but I have been seeing a periodic xl.Application.Run from the code above.   Does this have something to do with gencache?   should I be using win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch instead?

Comment: What does this mean "I have been seeing a periodic xl.Application.Run ..."?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to type out the xl.Application.Run periodic error.  Sometimes I'll get the "The RPC Server is unavailable" or "The remote procedure call as failed"  I started adding in some time.sleep() calls to see if when I'm running the macros if some additional timers/pauses were needed.